# Flutter Web Socket

Tags: flutter, websocket, whatsapp, flutter-web

I have developed a flutter app for WEB and Android I store transaction data using sembast. I want to sync the data between my mobile app and web app just like Whatsapp WEB.How do I implement this without sending data to all the user's but only the specified user with a unique Id.